Why don't charges on surface of current carrying wire move?
When a steady current flows through a wire, there is usually charges on the surface of the wire. These surface charges have an nonuniform distribution so that the electric field inside the wire is uniform and parallel to the wire.
But… If I understand correctly due to the nonuniform surface charge distribution there should be tangential electrical field on the surface of the wire, which is directed same as the current. If so, why don’t surface charge move in same direction as free charges in the bulk of conductor. In other words, what force makes the charges on the wire surface be stationary?

Why do you think this being true?"there is usually charges on the surface of the wire."

@trula that is part of standard physics explanation of how wires actually work. See the huge debate that Veritasium kicked off with the "energy does not flow in wires" video.


"why don’t surface charge move in same direction as free charges in the bulk of conductor." I think that is an approximation. Maybe they do move, but the surface is pretty thin and has high resistance, unlike the wire inside, so in usual DC conduction, surface current is considered negligible.


The entire wire feels a constant $\vec E=\rho\vec J$ field, and the constant $\vec J$ flow of current means that every bit of the surface charge that flowed tangentially to the next bit of the wire, is also being replaced by the charge that is coming from the back that flows into it. This steady state of affairs means that the non-uniform surface charge is easily kept there, and does not diminish away, at least until the power supply or battery stops supplying either of voltage or current.

so, your idea is that the surface charges actually flow too as bulk charges, but the distribution is constant. Right? If it is the case, then I find a phrase “stationary surface charges”, which I came across in the internet several times, to be quite confusing. It is distribution of the surface charges that stationary, not surface charges themselves.

Yes, but "distribution of the surface charges" is a mouthful.

P.S. In textbook Physics for Scientists and Engineers by Randall D. Knight there is the following text: "Note that the surface charges are not the moving charges of the current. Further, the current—the moving charges—is inside the wire, not on the surface. "
What do you think about that?

That is not a big disagreement. The surface current flow is not a big contributor. In fact, the magnetic field produced by the the general current flow tends to bind the current into the centre of the wire (in the DC case; only in the high frequency AC case is skin effect important) and so the contribution due to the surface current flow is necessarily not big

Frankly speaking, I thought the same. Thank you again!

Hello, I have another question here and I would be grateful if you help me again. If we assume that surface charges move, then what is the electric field on the surface of the wire that makes the distribution of surface charges be constant? The thing is that this field cannot be uniform along the wire, because if it would be then the distribution would shift in the direction of the current, so the distribution would not be constant.

The electric field tangential to the wire has to be constant, as dictated by the $\vec J=\sigma\vec E$ that we had seen earlier. The electric field perpendicular to the surface of the wire is essentially zero inside the wire and extremely complicated outside the wire.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
